# Integration by parts on set $\{u>0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Consider a $C^\infty$ function satisfying $\Delta u=f$ in $\Bbb R^n$. Suppose that the super-level set $\{u>0\}$ is bounded, so $\partial\{u>0\}$ is compact. Can one integrate by parts on this? Namely, if $\partial\{u>0\}$ were smooth, then 
$$\int_{\{u>0\}} |Du|^2=\int_{\partial\{u>0\}}u \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}-\int_{\{u>0\}}fu=-\int_{\{u>0\}}fu.$$
But $\partial\{u>0\}$ could be something strange. Is this kind of thing ok because $u=0$ on $\partial\{u>0\}$ anyway? I tried showing that $\{u>0\}$ is a set of finite perimeter, but no luck. The literature only seems to have results of this type for when $u$ is harmonic.

Comment: The smooth Urysohn lemma rules out anything as nice as finite-perimeter: just take some compact $X$ with infinite perimeter and construct a smooth $u$ to be $0$ on $X$ and positive elsewhere. Also, your displayed equation seems wrong: should the first integral be $\int |\nabla u|^2$ instead?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis You need something more than the Urysohn lemma I think, but it is indeed true that given any closed subset $K$, there is a nonnegative function $u$ such that $K=u^{-1}(0)$. So certainly not finite perimeter, but does that exclude the integral formula from being true?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps try an approximation argument: Sard's theorem tells you can find $\epsilon_k \searrow 0$ such that you can integrate by parts in $\int_{\{u>\epsilon_k\}} |Du|^2,$ so the problem is then controlling the boundary terms $\int_{\partial\{u>\epsilon\}} u \partial_n u = \epsilon \int_{u = \epsilon} |Du|$ as $\epsilon \to 0.$ My guess is that a funky enough $u$ could give a non-zero (or divergent) defect, but that really is just a guess.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  I had the same thought. Finite perimeter would disallow the divergence, so maybe one could construct a counterexample with a non-finite perimeter set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set $\Omega = \{u>0\}$ is exhausted by the sets $\Omega_\epsilon = \{u>\epsilon\}$, for positive $\epsilon>0$. By Sard's lemma, $\partial\Omega_\epsilon $ is smooth for a.e. $\epsilon$. For such $\epsilon$, consider the function $u_\epsilon = u-\epsilon$ on $\Omega_\epsilon$; integration by parts yields
$$
\int_{\Omega_\epsilon} |Du_\epsilon|^2 = -\int_{\Omega_\epsilon}fu_\epsilon
$$
hence
$$
\int_{\Omega_\epsilon} (|Du |^2 +fu) = \epsilon \int_{\Omega_\epsilon}f $$
As long as $\int_\Omega |f| < \infty$, the right hand side tends to zero as $\epsilon\to 0$. Hence 
$$
\int_{\Omega } (|Du |^2 +fu)
 = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\Omega_\epsilon} (|Du |^2 +fu) = 0
$$

Comment: Right, of course. When I did this I didn't realize $u_\epsilon=0$ on $\partial\Omega_\epsilon$ for some reason.